# How do you close a python - tkinter window, when the window object is encapsulated?

Tags: python, object, tkinter, exit, python-3.4

Ok, so this is from a larger project that I am working on, so I apologize if it looks messy.

The issue is that when I click the 'Exit Program' Button on the GUI, the window remains active.
I know that the button is working as when I hit the 'x' on the top right corner the window; the program closes, so the run variable has been set back to 0, which stops the code from looping.

My question is how do I get the window to be closed automatically when the exit button is clicked, because the root.destroy() method isn't doing it.

```
#imports
from tkinter import *
import random, pickle, shelve

#global vars
run = 0

class Window(Frame):
#the class that manages the UI window

    def __init__(self, master, screen_type = 0):
        """Initilize the frame"""
        super(Window, self).__init__(master)
        self.grid()
        if screen_type == 1:
            self.log_in_screen()

    def log_in_screen(self):
        #Program Exit Button
        self.exit = Button(self, text = " Exit Program ", command = self.end)
        self.exit.grid(row = 3, column = 0, columnspan = 2, sticky = W)

    def end(self):
        global run, root
        run = 0
        root.destroy()

#Main Loop
def main():
    global run, root
    run = 1
    while run != 0:
        root = Tk()
        root.title("Budget Manager - 0.6.1")
        root.geometry("400x120")
        screen = Window(root, screen_type = run)
        root.mainloop()

store = shelve.open("store.dat", "c")
main()
store.close()
```

Comment: I see the opposite of what you describe -- when I click the exit button, the program quits. If I destroy the window by clicking the window manager control a new one will pop up.

Comment: The command for the exit button should be root.quit.  A simple example http://www.java2s.com/Code/Python/GUI-Tk/Addsystemexitactiontoabutton.htm  Also pass root to the class's init method and use self.root instead of the more clumsy global root

Comment: @BryanOakley I didn't make that part clear. If I just hit the 'x' then yes, a new window will appear, however if I click 'exit', and then hit the 'x' then the program closes. What you have described is actually how I want the program to work. A simple 'click the exit button and its gone' system.

Comment: @OmniOrus: if you want "A simple "click the exit button and its gone" behavior, why are you creating multiple root windows in a loop?

Comment: @CurlyJoe OK, so slight issue with that Idea. I have tested the code from the link and I have the same issue as before. I hit the button and the window just stays there, unless I click the 'x'. I am starting to think that it may be my computer that's causing the problems as both you and 'Bryan Oakley' don't seem to be experiencing this problem.

Comment: @BryanOakley Simple in appearance for the user. I want the user to be able to just click the button and the program closes. The multiple root windows in a loop is there because I have multiple UI set ups that will appear over the course of the program and this set up allow me to switch which UI is being displayed by changing the value of the 'run' variable.

Comment: @OmniOrus: One final question: is your question really no more than "how can I make clicking on the "x" do the same as clicking on the "Exit program" button"?

Comment: @BryanOakley More like the other way around, how can I make clicking on the 'Exit Program' button do the same as clicking on the 'x'.

Comment: @OmniOrus: all the "x" button does is destroy the window. So, make the button call the destroy method without doing anything else. Though, this will make it impossible for your users to exit the program, since your exit button sets a flag that stops your infinite loop of creating root windows.

Comment: @BryanOakley Is there no way I could call the root.destroy method from another method? so I have to call it from the button?

Comment: @OmniOrus: of course you can call `root.destroy` from any method you want. You're already calling it in your exit method. I honestly don't understand your problem. The "x" button calls it automatically (unless you call the `protocol` method), your `end` function also calls it.

Comment: @OmniOrus: be aware, `destroy` does exactly and only what it says -- it destroys the window. Your code is essentially waiting for a window to be destroyed, and then it's recreating them. I don't think destroying windows is your real problem.

Comment: @OmniOrus: are you aware the "destroy the root window" does _not_ mean "exit the program"? All it means is that the window is destroyed and the call to `mainloop()` returns. You can choose to let the program exit, or you can have more code. Most Tkinter programs exit. You've choosen to have an endless loop of new windows created.

Comment: @BryanOakley It only loops so long as run is not 0. my end function sets the global run to 0, and then should destroy the window. Other functions in the over all program will work the same way, but they set run to a different number depending on the required UI, but the new UI only come up after the mainloop() returns, and I want the previous screen to be out of the way, to minimize confusion.

Comment: @BryanOakley Ok, I seen to have got it working. I removed the global root parts and it started working. Thanks for your help. Your advise has been very helpful over all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My question is how do I get the window to be closed automatically when
>   the exit button is clicked, because the root.destroy() method isn't
>   doing it.

The answer is: call `destroy()` on the root window. You say it isn't working, but the code you posted seems to work, and what `destroy()` is documented to do is exactly what you describe you want to have happen: it will destroy the window. Your code creates new toplevel windows in a loop, so maybe it only *appears* to not work since the old window id destroyed and the new window is created in the blink of an eye.

It seems like what you're really asking is "how can I make clicking on the "x" do the same as clicking on the "Exit program" button?". If that is the case, the answer is very straight-forward, even with your unconventional code that creates root windows in a loop.

To get the "x" button on the window frame to call a function instead of destroying the window, use the `wm_protocol` method with the `"WM_DELETE_WINDOW"` constant and the function you want it to call.

For example:

```
while run != 0:
    root = Tk()
    ...
    screen = Window(root, screen_type = run)
    root.wm_protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", screen.end)
    ...
    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

you could do something like the below. I've used it in my own projects etcand it works.

```
Mywin =tkinter.Tk()

def exit():
    Mywin.quit()
    # etc.
```